# Being able to scroll using flexbox chat application

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to build the following chat application:

[image]

I can't get the chat clients to scroll, and either the messages on the left side.

Can anyone put a snippet on how would you sort of build this?

Answer (score 0):

You might wrap client list component with Scrolling component like that

---

```
   <ScrollY>
      <ClientList />
  </ ScrollY>




 const ScrollY= (props) => {
    return (
      <div style={{overflowYX:'hidden', overflowY: 'scroll',dispaly:'none'}}>
          {props.children}
      </div>
  );
};
```

---

Comment: Thanks, Hagai, do you know how to approach it with TailWindCSS?